# I have to periodically `modprobe -r psmouse && modprobe psmouse` to get my touchpad buttons to work again

Tags: drivers, kernel, mouse, touchpad

I'm not really sure how to go about finding the *real* root-cause of this issue, but more than occasionally, my touchpad **buttons** stop functioning on my ThinkPad running Ubuntu. I'm able to get them functioning again by running:

```sh
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

I have the first-gen AMD ThinkPad T14s, and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, with the latest updates installed. I have **not** been able to successfully upgrade my firmware on this device since I bought it, but this issue seems to surface only a month or two after a fresh install.

How else can I debug this? Looking through my system logs, nothing obvious is jumping out at me:

dmesg:

```
sudo dmesg -w | grep psmouse
[    1.537565] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x7f3001)
[    1.549353] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x90, 0x18, 0x0f.
[    1.560808] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 80, c9
[    1.572329] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
[    1.596039] psmouse serio1: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
[    1.596087] psmouse serio1: elantech: SMbus companion is not ready yet
[ 4149.117518] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x7f3001)
[ 4149.129497] psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x90, 0x18, 0x0f.
[ 4149.143586] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 80, c9
[ 4149.155730] psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
[ 4149.179603] psmouse serio1: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
[ 4149.179696] psmouse serio1: elantech: SMbus companion is not ready yet
```

journalctl:

```
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x7f3001)
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x90, 0x18, 0x0f.
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 80, c9
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
Sep 20 18:51:40 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: SMbus companion is not ready yet
Sep 20 18:53:41 me-t14s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2801]: (==) AMDGPU(0): Silken mouse enabled
Sep 20 18:53:42 me-t14s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2801]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
Sep 20 18:53:42 me-t14s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2801]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse0)
Sep 21 14:17:58 me-t14s sudo[15526]: me : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/me ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe -r psmouse
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s sudo[15532]: me : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/me ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe psmouse
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x7f3001)
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Synaptics capabilities query result 0x90, 0x18, 0x0f.
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan sample query result 00, 80, c9
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Elan ic body: 0x10, current fw version: 0x3
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: Trying to set up SMBus access
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s kernel: psmouse serio1: elantech: SMbus companion is not ready yet
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2801]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech TrackPoint (/dev/input/mouse0)
Sep 21 14:17:59 me-t14s /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2801]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
```